# For this scenario, why is SQL Azure Database Performance Difference so much on Web and New Premium Editions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure, database-performance

We are migrating an website to SQL Azure and found a scenario where there is a very significant performance difference between our current hosting and azure database.

To be clear, the stored procedure code is written poorly and can be fixed but what I would like to understand is the reasons behind the performance difference.

Here is the offending code inside the procedure that is causing the problem

```
declare @curPinNumber int
set @curPinNumber = 183843692

declare @pinNumber int
set @pinNumber = 0
while @pinNumber < 10000
begin
    set @curPinNumber = @curPinNumber + 1
    insert into PinNumbers(pinNumber, pinNumberText, whenLastUsed, siteID) 
    values(@curPinNumber, right('0000' + cast(@pinNumber as varchar), 4), '1970-01-01', 999)
    set @pinNumber = @pinNumber + 1     
end
```

Here are the test results for the procedure

#### azure sql database web edition

- run #1:  41 seconds
- run #2:  37 seconds
- run #3:  37 seconds

#### standard edition s1 (15 DTU's - MS have since made S1 20 DTU's)

- run #1:  3 minutes, 44 seconds
- run #2:  3 minutes, 41 seconds
- run #3:  3 minutes, 42 seconds

#### standard edition s2 50 DTU's (not a mistake - all were very consistent)

- run #1:  1 minute, 51 seconds
- run #2:  1 minute, 51 seconds
- run #3:  1 minute, 51 seconds

#### premium edition P1 (100 DTU's)

- run #1:  56 seconds
- run #2:  55 seconds
- run #3:  55 seconds

#### premium edition P2 (200 DTU's)

- run #1:  33 seconds
- run #2:  33 seconds
- run #3:  34 seconds

*The two vm's below have seperate log and data disks.

#### sql on a virtual machine (basic, 1 core, 1.75gb ram. sql enterprise core edn)

- run #1:  53 seconds
- run #2:  50 seconds
- run #3:  51 seconds

#### sql on a virtual machine (basic, 2 core, 3.5gb ram.  sql enterprise core edn)

- run #1:  49 seconds
- run #2:  50 seconds
- run #3:  51 seconds

#### my desktop pc

- run #1:  3.7 seconds
- run #2:  3.1 seconds
- run #3:  3.1 seconds

#### current hosting (which has 7 year old equipment)

- run #1:  6.1 seconds
- run #2:  6.0 seconds
- run #3:  6.0 seconds

So my assumption here was a key factor is the logging and log flushes that are taking place, possibly the write ahead transaction logging http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186259.aspx

Adding a `BEGIN / COMMIT TRAN` block or joining from an existing preset table with 10,000 rows indeed gets the performance back to 1-2 seconds on the web edition of sql azure, and even faster on my local machine.

I would have expected Azure to be in a similar performance zone to my desktop or old hosting

My question is why on Azure is the difference so magnified?  I'm trying to judge if this just a corner case that we happened to pick up during testing and most importantly what things we should look out for in our migration.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think that the SQL Server license prevents you from publishing benchmarks.

Comment: @CSharpRocks I'm obviously not aware of any such limitation but happy for this to be taken down if need be.  I actually emailed MS with a link to this SO post for feedback I'm sure they'll be in touch if it's an issue.

Comment: This post was helpful to us, thanks. We ended up doing a similar comparison of Azure Business vs S1, S2, P1 tiers. Results here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25652839/1009125

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because of communication between the machine where you issue the batch from and the database service. Try and issue SET NOCOUNT ON first in the batch to turn off sending rows affected notifications back to the client.

Comment: This was my thought as well. Unclear, why the "current hosting" is so fast, though. Also, the perf increase after adding an explicit transaction is unexplained.

Comment: @user3657526 Actually SET NOCOUNT ON is actually already on.  When i tested this on azure database I was running the procedure using enterprise mgmt tools from.  When testing on the VM I was remoted into the VM using the mgmt tools.