# Comparing the new SQL Azure tiers to old ones

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Now that Microsoft made the new SQL Azure service tiers available (Basic, Standard, Premium) we are trying to figure out how they map to the existing ones (Web and Business).

Essentially, there are six performance levels in the new tier breakdown: Basic, S1, S2, P1, P2 and P3 (details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn741336.aspx)

Does anyone know how the old database tiers map to those six levels? For instance, is Business  equivalent of an S1? S2?

We need to be able to answer this question in order to figure out what service tiers/levels to migrate our existing databases to.

Comment: @Andrew: can you please elaborate on why this is opinion-based? I am looking for facts and, with lack of proper guidance from Microsoft, independent benchmarks are as good of an answer as we can get.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about choosing SQL Azure solutions; not programming.

Comment: Not sure why I originally closed as opinion based. This is what it should have been.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We just finished a performance comparison.

I can't publish our SQL queries, but we used 3 different test cases that match our normal activity. In each test case, we performed several queries with table joins and aggregate calculations (SUM, AVG, etc) for a few thousand rows. Our test database is modest - about 5GB in size with a few million rows.

A few notes: For each, we tested the my local machine which is a 5 year old iMac running Windows/SQL Server in a virtual machine ("Local"), SQL Azure Business ("Business"), SQL Azure Premium P1, SQL Azure Standard S2, and SQL Azure Standard S1. The basic tier seemed so slow that we didn't test it. All of these tests were done with no other activity on the system. The queries did not return data so network performance was hopefully not a factor.

Here were our results:

**Test One**

```
Local: 1 second
Business: 2 seconds
P1: 2 seconds
S2: 4 seconds
S1: 14 seconds
```

**Test Two**

```
Local: 2 seconds
Business: 5 seconds
P1: 5 seconds
S2: 10 seconds
S1: 30 seconds
```

**Test Three**

```
Local: 5 seconds
Business: 12 seconds
P1: 13 seconds
S2: 25 seconds
S1: 77 seconds
```

Conclusions:

After working with the different tiers for a few days, our team concluded a few things:

- P1 appears to perform at the same level as SQL Azure Business. (P1 is 10x the price)
- Basic and S1 are way too slow for anything but a starter database.
- The Business tier is a shared service so performance depends on what other users are on your server. Our database shows a max of 4.01% CPU, 0.77% Data IO ,0.14% Log IO and we're experiencing major performance problems and timeouts. Microsoft Support confirmed that we are "just on a really busy server."
- The Business tier delivers inconsistent service across servers and regions. In our case, we moved to a different server in a different region and our service is back to normal. (we view that as a temporary solution)
- S1, S2, P1 tiers seem to provide the same performance across regions. We tested West and North Central.
- Considering the results above, we're generally worried about the future of SQL Azure. The business tier has been great for us for a few years, but it's scheduled to go out of service in 12 months. The new tiers seem over priced compared to the Business tier.

I'm sure there are 100 ways this could be more scientific, but I'm hoping those stats help others getting ready to evaluate.

**UPDATE:**

Microsoft Support sent us a very helpful query to assess your database usage.

```
SELECT
       avg(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Average CPU Percentage Used',
       max(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Maximum CPU Percentage Used',
       avg(avg_physical_data_read_percent) AS 'Average Physical IOPS Percentage',
       max(avg_physical_data_read_percent) AS 'Maximum Physical IOPS Percentage',
                   avg(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Average Log Write Percentage',
       max(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Maximum Log Write Percentage',
       --avg(avg_memory_percent) AS 'Average Memory Used Percentage',
       --max(avg_memory_percent) AS 'Maximum Memory Used Percentage',
       avg(active_worker_count) AS 'Average # of Workers',
       max(active_worker_count) AS 'Maximum # of Workers'
FROM sys.resource_stats
WHERE database_name = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME' AND
start_time > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

The most useful part is that the percentages represent % of an S2 instance. According to Microsoft Support, if you're at 100%, you're using 100% of an S2, 200% would be equivalent to a P1 instance.

We're having very good luck with P1 instances now, although the price difference has been a shocker.

Comment: Wow, the pricing is insane! If I can trust the Azure Pricing Calculator, the pricing for the new tiers is not based on the database size, but on the performance level. We have a lot of databases ranging anywhere from a few dozes megabytes to 30GB. With the new pricing model, even Standard S1 is more going to be more expensive, and P1 will be unrealistic.

Comment: But what about running SQL Server on a VM in Azure? How does business P1 with the automatic backup and geo-replication compare to you having to license SQL Server, put it on a Large VM instance configure automatic backup jobs to Azure Storage and so on? Is P1 really a lot more expensive than the alternative?

Comment: It is worth noting that the %'s are averages, not peak.  If your database is not very well tuned or you have join queries that result in tables being loaded into memory you can see frequent timeouts.  We were estimated 30% average, 70% peak S2 using the above formula, this wasn't a good enough metric because our queries meant frequent timeouts.  We were initially considering going to P1 to cope.  In our case we did some heavy performance tuning and added a couple hacks and now are seeing in some cases, better performance, average of about 10%, peaks of 20% and are considering downgrading to S1

Comment: I'm getting an error with this query: Invalid object name 'sys.resource_stats'

Comment: You need to run the query against the master database

Comment: Running against master in a V12 server Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'avg_physical_data_read_percent'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'avg_physical_data_read_percent'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'active_worker_count'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'active_worker_count'.

Answer (score 12):

I am the author of the Azure SQL Database Performance Testing blog posts mentioned above.

Making IOPS to DTU comparisons is quite difficult for Azure SQL Database, which is why I focussed on row counts and throughput rates (in MB per second) in my tests.

I would be cautious about using the Transaction Rates quoted by Microsoft - their benchmark databases are rather small e.g. for Standard tier, which has a capacity of 250 GB, their benchmark databases for S1 and S2 are only 2 GB and 7 GB respectively.  At these sizes I suggest SQL Server is caching much/most of the database and as such their benchmark is avoid the worst of the read throttling that is likely to impact real world databases.

I have added a new post regarding the new Service Tiers hitting General Availability and making some estimates of the changes in performance around S0 and S1 at GA.

http://cbailiss.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/performance-in-new-azure-sql-database-performance-tiers/

Comment: Your blog posts are the best on the subject. If you're reading this thread, be sure to read this post!!

Answer (score 2):

There is not really any kind of mapping between the old and new offerings near as I can tell.  The old offerings the only thing that was really different between the "web" and "business" offering was the size the database was limited to.

However, on the new offerings each tier has performance metrics associated with them.  So in order to decide what offering you need to move your existing databases to you need to figure out what type of performance needs your application has.

Comment: Given that we have a large number of existing production environments, it is very important for us to have an idea of how our current environments will map into the brave new world of performance tiers. The lack of guidance is unsettling.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my comment to JChao's answer, someone performed an unofficial test with very interesting results: http://cbailiss.wordpress.com/2014/07/06/microsoft-azure-sql-database-performance-tests-summary/

Comment: That article http://cbailiss.wordpress.com/2014/07/06/microsoft-azure-sql-database-performance-tests-summary/ is the best I've found. Thanks!

Comment: Also bear in mind that since chris's article in July that MS have halved some of the proposed pricing and slightly increased (33%) the S1 performance from 15 to 20 DTU's.  There is still a big price  jump between S2 and P1 if your application performance falls between those.

Answer (score 2):

It appears in terms of size Web and Business fall between Basic and S1.  Here's a link that has a chart with the new and old tiers compared. It seems a little apple to oranges honestly so there isn't a direct mapping. Here's also a link specifically addressed to people currently on the Web and Business Tiers.

[Comparison of Tiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741340.aspx)

[Web and Business Edition Sunset FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741330.aspx)

Comment: How did you find out about Business falling between Basic and S1? As a matter of fact, your first link has a comment pointing to an unofficial benchmark claiming that Web/Business significantly outperforms Standard (including S2): http://cbailiss.wordpress.com/2014/07/06/microsoft-azure-sql-database-performance-tests-summary/

Comment: @DavidAirapetyan I said just in db size.